# python netCDF4 HDF error

Tags: python, debugging, hdf5, netcdf

I'm using python-netCDF4 library for reading/writing NetCDF files and have run into an issue, where writing character array fails for some reason, and the error message is not very informative, it is:

```
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1675, in     netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.sync (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:12137)
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

If this error comes from HDF C library, is it possible to force it to return more debugging information?

Unfortunately I cannot get the error with simplified code, so I cannot provide working example of producing the problem.

python2.7, py-netCDF4-1.1.8, macosx if this helps.

Comment: You've got line numbers there. Can you check what is happening at those lines in the source?

Comment: Post the part of your code that is leading to this error, as well.

Comment: @TimothyBrown Line numbers do not help much, error is raised where netcdf command "nc_sync" is called, but this is what I know already. And what nc_sync returns as error code is what is translated to "HDF error". I was wandering if there is a way to go to HDF library itself with debugger or make it print some additional information, without major effort of recompiling everything.

Comment: @N1B4 The code is a bit messy (does not help to solve the problem, I know), but the basic commands what I call are:

    rr=Dataset(...)
    for i in vars:
        a=createVariable(...)
        a[:]=inarray
        rr.sync

And the problem is caused by one variable, which is character array. The same code works well in many other cases.

Comment: What happens if you leave off the `sync`? Also you say you can't but we can't help without seeing some code.

Comment: @TimothyBrown If I leave out sync, I'll get the same error on .close() I'll try to put together a smaller example of the code that can reproduce the error,  current code is devided between too many functions and cannot be really separated from main program.